# Firebase Rule - Block user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using firebase for a chat app and I want to block some users by username (not uid of firebase auth).

Can make some rule on .write to match usernames and avoid the insert?

[image: my structure]

Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you could post your database structure (specially the part where you store these usernames) and your current rules.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes done! Thanks.

Comment: Want do you mean by "block"? Do you want to prevent them from accessing the database?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes prevent writing

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use Firebase Auth for this?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes because i'm using other login system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use your login system with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) Auth. You just need to use [Custom Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) with the Firebase Admin SDK on your server (or Cloud Functions). I highly recommend this as it would make it easy to set up simple rules to your database.

Now, if you're not planning to do that, there's an expensive workaround that you can use, but it's **not recommended** at all.

You can create a new node containing all the blocked users:

```
{
    "blocked":{
        "username1":true,
        "username2":true,
        "username4":true,
        "username5":true,
        "username7":true
    }
}
```

Then when you're writing data to the database, add one more field that contains the username of the user that is currently writing to the database. I see that your chat node already has this field, but if you have more nodes, you might want to add the field there as well.

And your database rules would be like this:

```
{
    "rules":{
        "chats":{
            "$chatId":{
                ".read":true,
                ".write":"root.child('blocked').child(newData.val().user).exists()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```